# taking input using scanf

Tags: c, input, output, scanf

*when i run this program this takes input for a two times even if scanf is used only once,WHY?????*

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<conio.h>
int main(){
   int a,b,i=1,product;
   printf("Enter the value of a\n");
   scanf("%d\n",&a);
   printf("Enter the value of b\n");
   scanf("%d\n",&b);
   while(i<b){
      product = i*3;
      if(product > a){
         printf("%d*3 = %d\n",i,product);
         }
         i = i + 1;
      }
  }
```

Comment: You have used `scanf()` twice, line no.6 and line no.8

Comment: "takes input for a two times even if scanf is used only once" --> Remove `'\n'` from `scanf("%d\n",...);`  Who or what text suggested doing that?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that was a typo

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i have use \n for printing next printf in new line can u explain what  problem is it causing

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it worked fine after removing \n from scanf

Comment: s_ssuyash, "i have use \n for printing next printf" is about `'\n'` in `printf()`.   My unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61005300/taking-input-using-scanf#comment107928322_61005300), before we get into your later  "what problem is it causing" , was about code's use of `'\n'` in `scanf()`.